# Table Header Fixed beneath Fixed Page Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The table header is fixed, but it is at the top of the page after scrolling. It works exactly how I want it, except the thead is fixed in the wrong place.

The table has an overflow-x:auto and the TD are using white-space:nowrap so the table expands to handle the content.

I need it to be fixed 140 pixels from the top or right below the Page Header.
I cant figure out how to offset this... Its close, but needs to take into account the overflow...

Here is JSFIDDLE - https://jsfiddle.net/rbla/1Ljuycbe/1/

Please look at the FIRST table... and the problem is with the OVERFLOW-X:AUTO - I need the cloned table to reflect this as well...

JQUERY

```
 ;(function($) {
   $.fn.fixMe = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
     var $this = $(this),
        $t_fixed;
     function init() {
        $this.wrap('<div class="container" />');
        $t_fixed = $this.clone();
        $t_fixed.find("tbody").remove().end().addClass("fixed").insertBefore($this);
        resizeFixed();
     }
     function resizeFixed() {
        $t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
           $(this).css("width",$this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth()+"px");
        });
     }
     function scrollFixed() {
        var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
        tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
        tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
        if(offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom)
           $t_fixed.hide();
        else if(offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
           $t_fixed.show();
     }
     $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
     $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
     init();
  });
     };})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function(){
   $("table").fixMe();
   $(".up").click(function() {
       $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: 0
   }, 2000);
   });
});
```

CSS

```
 h1, h2 {
       text-align: center;
       text-transform: uppercase;
      }

    .container {
       width: 90%;
       margin: auto;
       overflow-x:auto; /* MUST KEEP */
      }

     table {
       border-collapse:collapse;
       width:100%;
      }

     .blue {
       border:2px solid #1ABC9C;
      }

     .blue thead {
       background:#1ABC9C;
     }

     .purple{
       border:2px solid #9B59B6;
     }

.purple thead{
  background:#9B59B6;
}

thead {
  color:white;
}

th,td {
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px 0;
  white-space: nowrap; /* MUST KEEP */
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background:#ECF0F1;
}

tbody tr:hover {
background:#BDC3C7;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}

.fixed {
  top:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:auto;
  display:none;
  border:none;
}

.scrollMore {
  margin-top:10px;
}

.up {
  cursor:pointer;
}

.header {
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 140px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    }

 #pure {
   margin-top:200px;
 }
```

```js
;
(function($) {
  $.fn.fixMe = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        $t_fixed,
        $header_height = $('header').height();

      function init() {
        $this.wrap('<div class="container" />');
        $t_fixed = $this.clone();
        $t_fixed.find("tbody").remove().end().addClass("fixed").css({
          top: $header_height + "px"
        }).insertBefore($this);
        resizeFixed();
      }

      function resizeFixed() {
        $t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
          $(this).css("width", $this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth() + "px");
        });
      }

      function scrollFixed() {
        var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
          tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
          tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
        if (offset + $header_height < tableOffsetTop || offset + $header_height > tableOffsetBottom)
          $t_fixed.hide();
        else if (offset + $header_height >= tableOffsetTop && offset + $header_height <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
          $t_fixed.show();
      }
      $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
      $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
      init();
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table").fixMe();
  $(".up").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* MUST KEEP */
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.blue {
  border: 2px solid #1ABC9C;
}

.blue thead {
  background: #1ABC9C;
}

.purple {
  border: 2px solid #9B59B6;
}

.purple thead {
  background: #9B59B6;
}

thead {
  color: white;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* MUST KEEP */
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ECF0F1;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background: #BDC3C7;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.fixed {
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  display: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.scrollMore {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.up {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header {
  font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#pure {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">Fixed Header - 140PX</header>

<div id="pure">

  <h1>Table Fixed Header</h1>

  <h2>At Bottom of Fixed Header</h2>

  <h2>&darr; SCROLL &darr;</h2>



  <div class="container">

    <table class="blue">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Colonne 1</th>
          <th>Colonne 2</th>
          <th>Colonne 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non asdf asdf asdfsad fsdf asdf sadfsad sdf adf sad sadfasd fsf</td>
          <td>Mais Non asdf asdf asdfsad fsdf asdf sadfsad sdf adf sad sadfasd fsf</td>
          <td>Allo Non asdf asdf asdfsad fsdf asdf sadfsad sdf adf sad sadfasd fsf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <h2 class="scrollMore">&darr; SCROLL MORE &darr;</h2>

  <div class="container">
    <table class="purple">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Colonne 1</th>
          <th>Colonne 2</th>
          <th>Colonne 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <h2 class="up scrollMore">&uarr; UP &uarr;</h2>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixs the header problem with scrolling the header.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.fixMe = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        $t_fixed, $table_wrap, $table_header_wrap, $container,
        $header_height = $('header').height();

      function init() {
        $container = $this.parent();
        $table_header_wrap = $('<div>').addClass('table_header_wrap').insertAfter($this);
        $table_wrap = $('<div>').addClass('table_wrap').insertAfter($table_header_wrap).append($this);
        $t_fixed = $this.clone().find("tbody").remove().end().hide().appendTo($table_header_wrap);
        $table_header_wrap.css({
          top: $header_height + "px"
        }).on('scroll', header_wrap_scroll);
        resizeFixed();
      }

      function resizeFixed() {
        $table_header_wrap.width($container.width() + 10);
        //$table_wrap.width($container.width());
        $t_fixed.width($this.width() + 2);
        $t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
          $(this).css("width", $this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth() + "px");
        });
      }

      function scrollFixed() {
        var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
          tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
          tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
        if (offset + $header_height < tableOffsetTop || offset + $header_height > tableOffsetBottom)
          $t_fixed.hide();
        else if (offset + $header_height >= tableOffsetTop && offset + $header_height <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
          $t_fixed.show();
      }

      function header_wrap_scroll() {
        $table_wrap.scrollLeft($table_header_wrap.scrollLeft());
      }
      $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
      $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
      init();
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table").fixMe();
  $(".up").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.blue {
  border: 2px solid #1ABC9C;
}

.blue thead {
  background: #1ABC9C;
}

.purple {
  border: 2px solid #9B59B6;
}

.purple thead {
  background: #9B59B6;
}

thead {
  color: white;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* MUST KEEP */
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ECF0F1;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background: #BDC3C7;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.table_wrap {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.table_header_wrap {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.scrollMore {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.up {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header {
  font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#pure {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">Fixed Header - 140PX</header>
<div id="pure">
  <h1>Table Fixed Header</h1>
  <h2>At Bottom of Fixed Header</h2>
  <h2>&darr; SCROLL &darr;</h2>
  <div class="container">

    <table class="blue">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Colonne 1</th>
          <th>Colonne 2</th>
          <th>Colonne 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non asdf asdf asdfsad fsdf asdf sadfsad sdf adf sad sadfasd fsf</td>
          <td>Mais Non asdf asdf asdfsad fsdf asdf sadfsad sdf adf sad sadfasd fsf</td>
          <td>Allo Non asdf asdf asdfsad fsdf asdf sadfsad sdf adf sad sadfasd fsf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <h2 class="scrollMore">&darr; SCROLL MORE &darr;</h2>

  <div class="container">
    <table class="purple">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Colonne 1</th>
          <th>Colonne 2</th>
          <th>Colonne 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <h2 class="up scrollMore">&uarr; UP &uarr;</h2>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

This is the fix with scrollbar at the bottom of the table as per OP demand.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.fixMe = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        $t_fixed, $table_wrap, $table_header_wrap, $container,
        $header_height = $('header').height();

      function init() {
        $container = $this.parent();
        $table_header_wrap = $('<div>').addClass('table_header_wrap').insertAfter($this);
        $table_wrap = $('<div>').addClass('table_wrap').insertAfter($table_header_wrap).append($this).on('scroll', table_wrap_scroll);
        $t_fixed = $this.clone().find("tbody").remove().end().hide().appendTo($table_header_wrap);
        $table_header_wrap.css({
          top: $header_height + "px"
        });
        resizeFixed();
      }

      function resizeFixed() {
        $table_header_wrap.width($container.width());
        //$table_wrap.width($container.width());
        $t_fixed.width($this.width() + 2);
        $t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
          $(this).css("width", $this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth() + "px");
        });
      }

      function scrollFixed() {
        var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
          tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
          tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
        if (offset + $header_height < tableOffsetTop || offset + $header_height > tableOffsetBottom)
          $t_fixed.hide();
        else if (offset + $header_height >= tableOffsetTop && offset + $header_height <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
          $t_fixed.show();
      }

      function table_wrap_scroll() {
        $table_header_wrap.scrollLeft($table_wrap.scrollLeft());
      }
      $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
      $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
      init();
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table").fixMe();
  $(".up").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.blue {
  border: 2px solid #1ABC9C;
}

.blue thead {
  background: #1ABC9C;
}

.purple {
  border: 2px solid #9B59B6;
}

.purple thead {
  background: #9B59B6;
}

thead {
  color: white;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* MUST KEEP */
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ECF0F1;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background: #BDC3C7;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.table_wrap {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.table_header_wrap {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.scrollMore {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.up {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header {
  font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#pure {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">Fixed Header - 140PX</header>
<div id="pure">
  <h1>Table Fixed Header</h1>
  <h2>At Bottom of Fixed Header</h2>
  <h2>&darr; SCROLL &darr;</h2>
  <div class="container">

    <table class="blue">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Colonne 1</th>
          <th>Colonne 2</th>
          <th>Colonne 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non asdf asdf asdfsad fsdf asdf sadfsad sdf adf sad sadfasd fsf</td>
          <td>Mais Non asdf asdf asdfsad fsdf asdf sadfsad sdf adf sad sadfasd fsf</td>
          <td>Allo Non asdf asdf asdfsad fsdf asdf sadfsad sdf adf sad sadfasd fsf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <h2 class="scrollMore">&darr; SCROLL MORE &darr;</h2>

  <div class="container">
    <table class="purple">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Colonne 1</th>
          <th>Colonne 2</th>
          <th>Colonne 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <h2 class="up scrollMore">&uarr; UP &uarr;</h2>

</div>
```

Comment: This actually doesnt solve the issue - when you open this up in full browser width - take a look... the header gets chopped off...

Comment: try resizing this and you will see the issue.

Comment: @Ronald, Is it now working for you if you resize the screen?

Comment: When resized, Can you make the horizontal scrollbar appear at the bottom of the table?  Its close...

Comment: Yes. At first that was my solution. But in that case you need to scroll to the bottom of the table to scroll left and right. Think about it.

Comment: @Ronald check the update, inform me if this is what you wanted

Answer (score 2):

I've updated your JSFiddle to add those features. https://jsfiddle.net/g7wgp7gj/1/

The solution is to find and leverage the header's height in your calculations for when to display the floating table headers. This header height would also be used to dynamically set the floating table headers' "top" CSS property so it will be fixed under the header.

```
position: fixed;
top: <header height>px;
```

Comment: I am actually having issues with the width of the cloned table cells when table is resized

Comment: in which browser?

Comment: So I am working in Chrome. I have the table set to 98% width and  the cells are set up with percentage widths as well. The problem is that when I have content in a cell - the cell might expand ( i am using css white-space: nowrap ) - but when the clone happens, its just the header row so no expansion occurs, therefore the real header doesnt match up with the cloned header - and they are offset

Comment: So the original header goes outside the browser width because its within the echo "<div style='overflow-x:auto;'>"; but the cloned stays in the viewport... Im wondering if this is my issue.

Comment: And so I believe the problem lies in the content TD of the table. When I use this       $t_fixed.addClass("fixed").removeAttr("id").css({top: $header_height + "px"}).insertBefore($this);      instead of this     $t_fixed.find("tbody").remove().end().addClass("fixed").removeAttr("id").css({top: $header_height + "px"}).insertBefore($this);   ---> the header works fine ( the content has cloned ) but the TH is right on ... so I think the problem has to do with how the TD stretches when content is over flowing...

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/rbla/1Ljuycbe/1/    -  look at the first table

Comment: you need to resize the header based on the first body row widths every times the content changes

Answer (score 0):

*This is a suggested improvement on Munim Munna's accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48561229) above.*

---

I think I got it nailed down, but if for some reason this is inconsistent with what you want, feel free to tell me. The floating table headings do not retain the exact positions as the static ones beneath them, but the widths are the same, and scrolling over the table looks smooth. In the CSS for `.header`, I added this to make it a bit more presentable.

```
width:97%;
margin-left:1%;
margin-right:2%;
```

But one thing that caught my eye, I noticed this in **`resizeFixed()`**:

```
$table_header_wrap.width($container.width() + 10);
```

I believe this is what was causing the long table headings (`.blue`, and `.purple`) to "hang off" the right side of the table. I changed it to this.

```
$table_header_wrap.width($container.width() - 1);
```

Now the floating table header lines up with the body of the table.

```js
;
(function($) {
$.fn.fixMe = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
        $t_fixed, $table_wrap, $table_header_wrap, $container,
        $header_height = $('header').height();

        function init() {
            $container = $this.parent();
            $table_header_wrap = $('<div>').addClass('table_header_wrap').insertAfter($this);
            $table_wrap = $('<div>').addClass('table_wrap').insertAfter($table_header_wrap).append($this);
            $t_fixed = $this.clone().find("tbody").remove().end().hide().appendTo($table_header_wrap);
            $table_header_wrap.css({
                top: $header_height + "px"
            }).on('scroll', header_wrap_scroll);
            resizeFixed();
        }

        function resizeFixed() {
            $table_header_wrap.width($container.width() - 1);
            $t_fixed.width($this.width() + 2);
            $t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
                $(this).css("width", $this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth() + "px");
            });
        }

        function scrollFixed() {
            var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
                tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
                tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
            if (offset + $header_height < tableOffsetTop || offset + $header_height > tableOffsetBottom)
                $t_fixed.hide();
            else if (offset + $header_height >= tableOffsetTop && offset + $header_height <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
                $t_fixed.show();
        }

        function header_wrap_scroll() {
            $table_wrap.scrollLeft($table_header_wrap.scrollLeft());
        }
        $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
        $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
        init();
    });
};
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table").fixMe();
    $(".up").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

```css
h1, h2 {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 90%;
}

table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    max-width:100%;
}

table thead {
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.fixed {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:inherit;
}

.blue {
    border: 2px solid #1ABC9C;
}

.blue thead {
    background: #1ABC9C;
}

.purple {
    border: 2px solid #9B59B6;
}

.purple thead {
    background: #9B59B6;
}

thead {
    color: white;
}

th, td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* MUST KEEP */
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ECF0F1;
}

tbody tr:hover {
    background: #BDC3C7;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.table_wrap {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.table_header_wrap {
    position: fixed;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.scrollMore {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.up {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header {
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 97%;
    margin-left:1%;
    margin-right:2%;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 140px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#pure {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">Fixed Header - 140PX</header>
<div id="pure">
    <h1>Table Fixed Header</h1>
    <h2>At Bottom of Fixed Header</h2>
    <h2>&darr; SCROLL &darr;</h2>
    <div class="container">

    <table class="blue">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Colonne 1</th>
          <th>Colonne 2</th>
          <th>Colonne 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non asdf asdf asdfsad fsdf asdf sadfsad sdf adf sad sadfasd fsf</td>
          <td>Mais Non asdf asdf asdfsad fsdf asdf sadfsad sdf adf sad sadfasd fsf</td>
          <td>Allo Non asdf asdf asdfsad fsdf asdf sadfsad sdf adf sad sadfasd fsf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

    <h2 class="scrollMore">&darr; SCROLL MORE &darr;</h2>

    <div class="container">
    <table class="purple">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Colonne 1</th>
          <th>Colonne 2</th>
          <th>Colonne 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Non</td>
          <td>Mais</td>
          <td>Allo !</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    
    <h2 class="up scrollMore">&uarr; UP &uarr;</h2>
    
</div>
```

I hope this is of some help to you.

Comment: This is just a slight improvement of my answer. This should be posted as a comment to my answer. Not as a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

I have modified your js to do what you wanted [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Ljuycbe/4/)

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.fixMe = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
         var $this = $(this),
            $t_fixed,
            $header_height = $('header').height();
         function init() {
            $this.wrap('<div class="container" />');
            $t_fixed = $this.clone();
            // width matching added
            $t_fixed.find("tbody").remove().end().addClass("fixed").css({top: $header_height + "px", "width":$this.width()+"px"}).insertBefore($this);
            //scroll attachment between elements
            $this.parent().on('scroll',function(e){
                $t_fixed.css("margin-left",-$this.parent().scrollLeft()+"px");
            });
            //resizing fix
            var table = $this;
            $(window).on('resize',function(){
                $t_fixed.css('width',table.width()+"px");
            });
            resizeFixed();
         }
         function resizeFixed() {
            $t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
               $(this).css("width",$this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth()+"px");
            });
         }
         function scrollFixed() {
            var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
            tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
            tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
            if(offset + $header_height < tableOffsetTop || offset + $header_height > tableOffsetBottom)
               $t_fixed.hide();
            else if(offset + $header_height >= tableOffsetTop && offset + $header_height <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
               $t_fixed.show();
         }
         $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
         $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
         init();
      });
   };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("table").fixMe();
   $(".up").click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
   }, 2000);
 });
});
```

Comment: The headers dont match up when you resize